# Salesforce1 app without using login

Tags: salesforce1-app, salesforce1-platform

I have a public page which should be accessible by all the users in my organization on mobile devices but they do not have salesforce licences.

Is it possible to create a Salesforce1 page which is accessible by all users without using login credentials?

Or do we need to use Salesforce Mobile SDK to create such an app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the Salesforce Mobile SDK - Salesforce1 does not provide any facility for viewing public pages.